# Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, libv8

I get error when trying to bundle install:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name (https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14.gem)
    An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

Run manually

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'
```

And run again bundle install